# Running Windows 2004 with defective RAM

Tags: memory, memory-management, memtest86+, windows-10-v2004

Are there any solution to run Windows 10 **2004** with a defective RAM module?
Previous [solution](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/whea/how-to-manage-the-pfa-memory-list) :

1. `bcdedit /set {badmemory} badmemorylist 0x.... 0x...`
2. `bcdedit /set badmemoryaccess no`

doesn't work on Windows 10 2004

Comment: Those commands only function with ECC memory it has nothing to do with the version of Windows you are using.  Why aren’t you just replacing the defective memory?

Comment: Those commands works before Windows 10 2004. Replacing memory costs money

Comment: They still work;  if they don’t work you must not have ECC memory

Comment: Do you have 2004? Here is one more confirmation: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/starting-with-windows-10-2004-the-pfa-memory-list/4148df72-851d-4618-8181-d785d802c8c7, that it doesn't work

Comment: I can confirm that this still doesn't work a year later. Seems like Microsoft broke it. In a blog, someone else mentioned "bcdedit /set badmemorylist" worked for them a year ago, but that also didn't work for me. I also found [BadMemory](https://github.com/prsyahmi/BadMemory) which does something similar using drivers, but that seems have been broken recently too...

Answer (score 0):

Definitely not a solution that will work for everyone, but if you're lucky like me, and the bad memory region is near the end of the range (mine was between 32266mb to 323944mb), you can use the `bcdedit /set {current} truncatememory [bytes]`  to basically cut off the end of your RAM. Worked perfectly for me. You can also set it from `msconfig > boot > advanced options > maximum memory`. That being said, I had to disable Secure Boot for it to work.

I haven't tried this, but I wonder if you could swap around your ram sticks to also push the problematic area closer to the end region.